# Python/Pandas - 2 multi-index DataFrames visually the same, but not equal?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am using 2 ways to feed a multi-index pandas DataFrame:

- one that initializes it with values,
- one that fills it row per row (I don't care about the speed, I have to do it this way as I have each new row after different computations, and not all at once)

Please, both DataFrames 'looks' the same, but pandas tells me they are not.
What should I do so that they are the same?

```
 import attr
 import pandas as pd

 @attr.s(frozen=True)
 class CDE(object):
     name : str = attr.ib()
     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

 # Method 1: filling it row per row.
 rmidx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]], codes=[[],[]], names=['CDE','period'])
 c_array = [['Column', 'Column'],['First', 'Last']]
 cmidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(c_array)
 summary1 = pd.DataFrame(index = rmidx, columns=cmidx)
 mcde1 = CDE(name='hi')
 mcde2 = CDE(name='ho')
 values = [[20,30],[40,50]]
 period = '5m'
 summary1.loc[(mcde1, period),('Column',)]=values[0]
 summary1.loc[(mcde2, period),('Column',)]=values[1]

 # Method 2: all at once.
 columns = summary1.columns
 rows = summary1.index.names
 index_label = [[mcde1,mcde2],[period,period]]
 summary2 = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index_label, columns=columns)
 summary2.index.names = rows

 In [2]:summary1
 Out[2]: 
            Column     
             First Last
 CDE period            
 hi  5m         20   30
 ho  5m         40   50

 In [3]:summary2
 Out[3]: 
            Column     
             First Last
 CDE period            
 hi  5m         20   30
 ho  5m         40   50
```

But

```
 summary1.equals(summary2)
 False
```

Why is that so?
Thanks for any advice on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc `This function requires that the elements have the same dtype as their
respective elements in the other Series or DataFrame.` But if you do

```
summary1.dtypes, summary2.dtypes
```

You would get

```
(Column  First    object
         Last     object
 dtype: object,
 Column  First    int64
         Last     int64
 dtype: object)
```

This is because when you create an empty data frame

```
summary1 = pd.DataFrame(index = rmidx, columns=cmidx)
```

the default `dtype` is `object`. Therefore, whenever you append a new row, the data is converted/masked as the given `dtype`. On the other hand, if you create a data frame with given data, `pandas` will try to guess the best `dtype`, in this case `int64`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Please, how can I define the type of a given column when using multiindex? If I use `summary1 = summary1.astype({'Column':float64})` there is no error message, but I checked dtypes, and it stays object. I want to select the column because I can have other columns later on, with a different dtype. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can pass a single `dtype`, e.g. `dtype=float` to `pd.DataFrame()`. If you want to specify different `dtype` for different columns, you need to handle them manually after initialization.

Comment: Yes, but how? how can I select a column when using multi index? It does not seem to work. Thanks for your help.